# Multi query params not working in window.open url

Tags: javascript

The below piece of code is not working to send two query params, but if I send only one query param then it's working.

What's wrong with appending second query param to url? Using jsf h : link tag.

```
onclick="window.open('./test.xhtml?respRelaRef=1234&type=5','Responses','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=750,height=600'); return false;"
```

Comment: unclear how it would not be working. The issue is not with this code. Maybe you are cached with an old response.

Comment: Thank you  epascarello for your response, its working after adding &amp; it should be like this ./test.xhtml?respRelaRef=1234&amp;type=5